# Use Next.js 13 deploy on Vercel has error about can not find file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

In dev mode, it's normal operation and running successfully.
If run `'next start'` command, it can access successful too.
But if I deploy my repo on Vercel, it's looks like this:
[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRXtD.png)

This is my repo: https://github.com/bantangzm/bantang-blog

I really want to understand that what is happen, Thank you for your answering.

I tried to change my blog contents fold position into other directory, but it seems like error too.

Comment: it might be because you access something in content with path `public/contents/something.md` rather than just `contents/something.md`. In Next js all file in public folder is static thus you can access it without specifying `public` path

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?